# Natural density of solvable quintics

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, galois-theory

A [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1017447/98602) asked about the topological density of solvable monic quintics with rational coefficients in the space of all monic quintics with rational coefficients. Robert Israel gave a nice proof that both solvable and unsolvable quintics are dense in $\Bbb Q^5$. A natural (non-topological) way to ask about the relative density of solvable quintics in all quintics is to ask about their natural density, as follows:

Write our quintics as $x^5+a_0x^4 + \dots + a_4$, with $a_i \in \Bbb Z$. Write $$f(N) := \frac{\text{# of solvable quintics with } |a_i| < N}{(2N+1)^5}.$$ Robert Israel's answer to the linked question gives some data that supports our intuition that yes, the solvable quintics are in fact extremely rare. Do we indeed have $\lim_{N \to \infty} f(N) = 0$? Are there known nice asymptotics for $f(N)$?

Comment: I feel like it has been proved that 100% (in the limit) of quintics have Galois group equal to $S_5$, hence in particular are unsolvable.

Comment: @GregMartin I would be surprised if this wasn't the case, especially given the computational evidence for it. I'm especially interested in the asymptotics, though, as $f(N)$ seems to go to $0$ *extremely* quickly.

Comment: What are you looking for that isn't already in http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1027334/448 and the mathoverflow questions it links to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/58397/ http://mathoverflow.net/questions/28453 ?

Comment: Nothing, @DavidSpeyer; I wasn't aware of that answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We can in fact give a stronger result:

Let $P_N$ denote the set of monic polynomials of degree $n > 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ whose coefficients all have absolute value $< N$. S. D. Cohen gave in [*The distribution of Galois groups of integral polynomials*](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1256048323)
(Illinois J. of Math., **23** (1979), pp. 135-152) asymptotic bounds for the ratio in the above limit, and reformulating his statement with some trivial algebra gives (at least asymptotically) that
$$\frac{\#\{p \in P_N : \text{Gal}(p) \not\cong S_n\}}{N^n} \ll \frac{\log N}{\sqrt{N}};$$
note that the limit of the ratio on the right-hand side as $N \to \infty$ is $0$.
This implies a fortiori for $n = 5$ that
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{\#\{p \in P_N : \text{Gal}(p) \text{ is solvable}\}}{N^n} = 0,$$
since for quintic polynomials $p$, $\text{Gal}(p)$ is unsolvable iff $\text{Gal}(p) \cong A_5$ or $\text{Gal}(p) \cong S_5$.

Some similar results were produced a few decades earlier: B. L. van der Waerden showed in [*Die Seltenheit der Gleichungen mit Affekt*](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=GDZPPN002276607), (Mathematische Annalen **109**:1 (1934), pp. 13–16) that the above ratio has limit zero (at least when one allows nonmonic polynomials and adjusts the denominator accordingly, which is probably inessential).

For more see [this mathoverflow.net question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58397/the-galois-group-of-a-random-polynomial) and this old [sci.math question](http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/99/galois_rnd). Closely related questions on math.se include [Is the Galois group associated to a random polynomial solvable with probability 0?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275937/is-the-galois-group-associated-to-a-random-polynomial-solvable-with-probability) and (my own) [How often are Galois groups equal to $S_n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/939103/how-often-are-galois-groups-equal-to-s-n) .

(This answer is more-or-less a duplicate of [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1027334/155629) to the [question linked in OP's question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1017447/are-most-rational-quintics-unsolvable/1027334).)

Answer (score 0):

We can get a lower bound on the probability by condlsidering Cayley's resolvent for the case of depressed quintics (with the fourth degree term zeroed out). As described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4736869/248217), a depressed quintic

$y^5+py^3+qy^2+ry+s=0$

is guaranteed solvable if the expression

$-p^6+28p^4r-16p^3q^2-176p^2r^2-80p^2qs+224pq^2r-64q^4+400ps^2+320r^3-1600qrs$

equals zero, for then the Cayley resolvent is guaranteed to have zero as the required rational root.

If all coefficients in the depressed quintic are $O(N)$, then the above expression is $O(N^6)$ dominated by the $-p^6$ term. Thus the probability of hotting zero is **$O(N^{-6})$ and this must be considered a lower boubd for the probability of the depressed quintic being soluble.**

We can improve this bound by reckoning with **dimensional consistency.** The coefficients $p,q,r,s$ effectively have different units -- $p$ has units of $y^2$, $q$ has units of $y^3$, $r$ and $s$ respectively have unuts of $y^4$ and $y^5$. Thus means the terms in the expression we are targeting for zero remain $O(N^6)$ if

$p=O(N),q=O(N^{1.5}), r=O(N^2),s=O(N^{2.5}).$

For instance, picking the term $+400ps^2$, we get $O(N)[O(N^{2.5})]^2=O(N^6)$. So we have the lower bound:

$\color{blue}{p=O(N),q=O(N^{1.5}), r=O(N^2),s=O(N^{2.5})\implies \text{Probability of solvability}\ge O(N^{-6})}.$