# The most generic radicals-solvable quintic

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quintics

It's well known that it is impossible to solve a generic quintic equation in terms of radicals involving its coefficients. However: what's the "most generic" quintic equation that is still possible to solve using radicals?

If we think of a quintic as $ax^5+bx^4+cx^3+dx^2+ex+f = 0$ then "the most generic" here would mean such an equation that describes the largest solvable subset of quintics. There certainly exist some subsets of quintics that are solvable, a good example is $ax^5+b=0$ , but I want to know what's the most generic look of a solvable quintic is.

Comment: A fascinating book: http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/Quintic/quintic.pdf

Comment: I'm now curious if the set of solvable quintics is connected (viewed as a subset of R^6), simply connected, etc.

Comment: Have you seen this question and its answers https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1019449/305862 ?

Comment: Would something like [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4377484/functional-inverse-of-z-1w-cdotswn-1/4378436#4378436) help? Also [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10910-018-0985-3) if a polynomial can be depressed into a trinomial.

Comment: @BerenGunsolus This question doesn't make sense: One can only ask whether a quintic is solvable when it has rational coefficients.

Comment: Suppose I mean for it to be solvable with radicals, allowing use of the coefficients. In this sense x^5=e is "solvable"

Comment: The answer is if one of the roots is made from radicals, then so must the other $4$ since factoring the general quintic using a radical root will give a general quartic which always has radical roots. Right?